# Почему - раек?

Tags: этимология

Здравствуйте!
Насколько я знаю, задние ряды в театра раньше назывались раек. А почему? Это от слова "рай" или от какого-то другого?
Заранее благодарю за ответы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А.  Раёк – это вид кукольного театра в России на ярмарках в 18 - 19 вв.:
Это ящик с отверстиями, снабжёнными увеличительными стёклами, через которые зрители рассматривали вращающиеся внутри картинки; показ таких картинок, сопровождавшийся шутливыми рифмованными пояснениями, прибаутками. «Райком кормился дедушка, Москву да Кремль показывал (Некрасов).

Содержание показываемых картин весьма разнообразно: коронация государей, прием иностранных гостей, победы русского оружия, купцы, торгующие пылью и ветром, известные разбойники, пожары, виды столиц и заграничных городов. Показывание картин раешник сопровождает комментарием, по большей части юмористического свойства. Например:  Бисмарк в его характеристике "имеет три волоса, а поет на 33 голоса". Перед зрителем является и "наша русская знать, что любит денежки мотать: едет в Париж с золота мешком, а возвращается с палочкой пешком".

Происхождение "райка" и самого названия его может быть объяснено тем, что в основании панорамы когда-то лежало "Райское действо", известное в России еще в самом начале XVIII века; образец его мы имеем в "Жалостной комедии об Адаме и Еве", изданной Тихонравовым , где дьявол, а отчасти и прародители, играют комическую роль. Постепенно осложняясь новыми комическими сценами, райское действо сначала отступило на задний план, а затем исчезло; остались картины лишь светского содержания.
http://alcala.ru/brokgauz-slovari/izbrannoe/slovar-R/R1396.shtml

Б. Раёк – театральная галёрка (уменьш. от  рай)
«Театр уж полон, ложи блещут...В райке нетерпеливо плещут».  «Почтим его! Припомним зал, Где от райка до кресел, Мужик последний хохотал, Последний фат был весел».  «Я не хочу, чтоб мне рукоплескал раек».

«Худшие места на самом верхнем ярусе назывались ГАЛЕРЕЕЙ (неофициально «ГАЛЁРКОЙ») или, в обиходе, РАЙКОМ. Последнее слово придумано не без юмора: действительно, до рая, расположенного на небе, добраться нелегко. Вот как обыгрываются слова «рай, раек» в «Обыкновенной истории» Гончарова: «За место подле вас я не взял бы места в раю», – говорит Юлии влюбленный в нее Сурков. «Если в театральном, верю!» – насмешливо отвечает она». 
http://wordweb.ru/en_ru_byt/13_50.htm